# BDD and TDD for node.js?

Tags: node.js, rspec, tdd, cucumber, bdd

What is used for BDD and TDD with node.js?

I'm used to use Cucumber + RSpec. What's a good combo for node.js?

thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Update**

[Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) gets my vote now!

---

You could have a look at the [testing modules section](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-testing) from the node.js modules page. For example [Vows](http://vowsjs.org/) is a pretty popular BDD framework.

> Vows is a behavior driven development framework for Node.js.

Comment: Mocha's `bdd` interface gets pretty close to RSpec, but it still lacks the lazy `let`/`subject` niceties. I created a separate interface for mocha called `lazy-bdd` that has these additions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-lazy-bdd

Answer (score 18):

Check out [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) - [(github)](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha)

Also [mocha-cakes](https://github.com/quangv/mocha-cakes), my attempt for Cucumber syntax on mocha.

Comment: Why *should* I use cucumber syntax with mocha _now_?

Answer (score 15):

If you are used to rspec, [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) is pretty nice.  I've not used it on Node.js, but I have used it for testing a backbone app.  It's syntax is very similar to rspec.  Taken from the site above:

```
describe("Jasmine", function() {
  it("makes testing JavaScript awesome!", function() {
    expect(yourCode).toBeLotsBetter();
  });
});
```

It's listed in the link provided by Alfred above, but since folks listed Vows as an example, I figured I'd give Jasmine a bump, especially since it's syntactically similar to rspec ;)

Answer (score 9):

There is the 'Vows' project for BDD on Node http://vowsjs.org, looks pretty nice. It's a bit different from RSpec/Cucumber, but it's pretty fun

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little later, but what you're looking for is Kyuri: https://github.com/nodejitsu/kyuri

"kyuri is a node.js Cucumber implementation with a few extra asynchronous keywords. it supports 160+ languages and exports to VowsJS stubs"

Also, nodejitsu seems to have built a web app for managing a project Kyuri feature specs in a collaborative way, it's named "prenup", I would give it a look.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try [yadda](http://github.com/acuminous/yadda). It plugs into other test  libraries including mocha, jasmine, casper & webdriver, but also lets you write proper feature files instead of merely annotating you tests in situ. A typical test might look like...

```
var Yadda = require('yadda');
Yadda.plugins.mocha();

feature('./features/bottles.feature', function(feature) {

   var library = require('./bottles-library');
   var yadda = new Yadda.Yadda(library);

   scenarios(feature.scenarios, function(scenario, done) {
      yadda.yadda(scenario.steps, done);
   });
});
```

And the feature file...

```
Feature: Mocha Asynchronous Example

Scenario: A bottle falls from the wall

Given 100 green bottles are standing on the wall
when 1 green bottle accidentally falls
then there are 99 green bottles standing on the wall
```

And output...

```
Mocha Asynchronous Example
✓ A bottle falls from the wall 

1 passing (12ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Buster.JS](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/#). Created by Christian Johansen, who literally wrote [the book on javascript testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321683919).

Buster supports both TDD and [BDD](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/overview/#bdd-syntax). It does browser testing with browser automation (think JsTestDriver), QUnit style static HTML page testing, testing in headless browsers (PhantomJS, jsdom), and more.

Answer (score 1):

Package **a**
(bdd and mocking)
https://npmjs.org/package/a

Very compact syntax, context separated from acts, chainable acts.
Easy Cmd line runner that searches recursively.

Answer (score 1):

**Unit tests**: [Mocha](https://npmjs.org/package/mocha) is great for unit tests.

**BDD tests** If you want a BDD test framework for Node.js then I'd recommend the [Cucumber](https://npmjs.org/package/cucumber) package.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same concern last month .

**For BDD :**

Though Mocha itself provides BDD style by their describe and it statements.

For styles like cucumber , you can try :

- mocha-cakes
- mocha-gherkin
- cucumber.js
- kyuri
- mocha-cucumber

They all have their own styles. I am sorry I can not provide working snippets now , let me know @Donald which one you select. Would like to know your insight.

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for a good Gherkin implementation, found mocha-cakes/mocha-cakes-2 which were nice but not very full featured. So I build my own with mocha as the base, which has parity with the gherkin language including Scenario Outlines. It also makes it easy to reference the data in your test. Its different to cucumber.js as its all inline not separate files. You can find the project here:

[livedoc-mocha](https://github.com/dotnetprofessional/LiveDoc/tree/master/packages/livedoc-mocha)