# Testing Meteor Packages - Alternatives to TinyTest?

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, meteorite

What are the current options for testing custom-built Meteor packages? Is there anything out there other than the built-in TinyTest?

Found [this question from a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987525/meteor-test-driven-development), but my question is specifically about testing Meteor packages, not your core app.

Has anyone used [Laika](http://arunoda.github.io/laika/) for testing their own packages?

Comment: The guys at differential are writing a [book about testing](http://testingmeteor.com/) which will probably cover this answer in detail, but it's still a work in progress.

Comment: @DavidWeldon: Differential guys have joined efforts with [Sam Hatoum](http://stackoverflow.com/users/971615/sam-hatoum) and have released http://meteortesting.com - *the* book on testing nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor's testing support is quite in flux at the moment (June 2014). I imagine most people will stick with Tinytest until the community develops a better solution that supports better UI tests and end-to-end tests.

https://github.com/xolvio/velocity is trying to unify a bunch of testing frameworks to have Meteor support. You may want to check out their progress at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/velocity-core.

Comment: Indeed, the state of testing for meteor seems a bit lacking currently. Thanks for pointing out velocity though.

Answer (score 0):

[Velocity](http://velocity.meteor.com) is now the [officially sanctioned](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/07/14/meteor-testing-framework-velocity) testing framework for Meteor, and there's a book about it - [Meteor Testing](http://meteortesting.com).