# Use intern js with meteor

Tags: meteor, intern

I'm starting a project on Meteor and i'm trying to use intern js for my tests.
So, I have a mongoDB collection and i'm trying to run tests on it.

I have this statement on the file I want to test

```
this.Teams = new Meteor.Collection('teams');
```

And i get this error at this line :

```
ReferenceError : Meteor is not defined
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Regards

Comment: How are you loading Meteor into the environment? How are you running Intern?

Comment: @CSnover, please verify my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to test Meteor application with TheIntern.js.

**Though it is as per my need.** But still I think it may lead someone to the right direction and I am sharing what I have done to resolve this issue.

There is a `execute` function which allows us to run JS code thorugh which we can access browsers `window` object and hence `Meteor` also.

Want to know more about [execute](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Session.html#execute)

This is how my `test suite` looks for **Functional Testing**

```js
define(function (require) {
    var registerSuite = require('intern!object');
    var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');
    registerSuite({
        name: 'index',

        'greeting form': function () {
            var rem = this.remote;
            return this.remote
                .get(require.toUrl('localhost:3000'))
                .setFindTimeout(5000)
                .execute(function() {
                        console.log("browser window object", window)
                        return Products.find({}).fetch().length
                    })
                .then(function (text) {
                    console.log(text)
                    assert.strictEqual(text, 2,
                        'Yes I can access Meteor and its Collections');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

**To know more, this is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/harpreetkhalsagtbit/55022792c1b6ab4367c4)**

Note: I am still in very early phase with this solution. I don't know whether I can do complex testing with this or not. But i am pretty much confident about it.

Answer (score -1):

You need use a special framework for writing unit-test for meteor app. See [Meteor test driven development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987525/meteor-test-driven-development)

*Note:* 'Meteor.Collection' is deprecated namespace. Use 'Mongo.Collection'

Comment: So there is no way I can use Intern js to test my app ?

Comment: This is absolutely not true. You can test any application written using any framework with Intern.

Comment: How then ? I didn't see any examples on internet

Comment: Since I discovered the build method in Meteor, I think it's possible to use internjs. Indeed, when you build your app, you use node to run it instead of meteor. I'll do some tests and keep you guys in touch